# How to load dataGridView in the backgroundworker from dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a datagridview in my form which it takes time to load from database. I need to implement this process in the backGroundWorker Thread. But I Don't have any idea about that.
I googled it but I couldn't find a solution for dataset or tableAdapter method.

---

this is my code :

```
private void frmNewExpense_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadForm();
     fillDataGrid();
}

private void LoadForm()
{     
      this.tbl_AccountsTableAdapter.Fill(this.personalExpensesDataSet.tbl_Accounts);
      this.tbl_ExpSubCatsTableAdapter.Fill(this.personalExpensesDataSet.tbl_ExpSubCats);
      this.tbl_ExpenseCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.personalExpensesDataSet.tbl_ExpenseCategory);

      lblAccountAmount.Text = new oldSeparateThounsands().separate(lblAccountAmount.Text);

      oldGetPersianDate gpd = new oldGetPersianDate();
      gpd.dt = DateTime.Now;
      txtDate.Text = gpd.fn_persianDate();

      txtDesc.Text = txtAmount.Text = String.Empty;
}

private void fillDataGrid()
{
      this.view_Top100ExpensesTableAdapter.Fill(this.personalExpensesDataSet.View_Top100Expenses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create `backgroundworker` in `pageload` event class as follows

`m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                    (m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
m_oWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;`

`m_oWorker_DoWork` is method where you will use adapters and dataset/datatables to fill and databind the grid (it's a method that will call your `LoadForm();`). On completion, backgroundworker will call `m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` where you will call your method `filldatagrid()` to bind data to grid

Comment: How can I send values to UI. because this method doesn't fill the gridView.